# For any two sets A and B, if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective, then if A is countable, B must be countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So i was given two questions you either prove or disprove them.

A) For any two sets A and B, if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective, then if A is countable, B must be countable.

B) For any two sets A and B, if $f: A \to B$ is surjective, then if A is countable, B must be countable.

I know Every subset of a countable set is countable and I know i have to use injectivity of f to create a bijection for A but i don't know how. Also for B im quite clueless does it follow A?

Comment: Were you told to *prove* or were you told to "prove or disprove" these two statements?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You could do either depending on whether you think it is true or false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Both: this is a new, inconsistent theory.

Comment: I think that A) is false and B) is true. For example, the mapping $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ which identifies $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is injective. It is easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: @ChristopherW: I would suggest changing the letters so you either use parts 1,2 , or change the letters you use for the sets to avoid using the letters $A,B$ for both. It seems kind of confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (A) consider a function that takes an integer in $\mathbb Z$ to itself , with $\mathbb Z$ living in $\mathbb R$.

For (B), we have hat $B=f(A)$, so that $|B|=|f(A)|$, and since every element in $A$ maps into a single element in $B$, we have $|B|\leq |f(A)|$. Can you use your idea that every subset of a countable set is countable to show how $f(a)$ can be made into a "subset" of $A$? , i.e., find an injection between $A$ and $f(A)$?

Comment: Wait so A would not be true because $\Bbb R$ is uncountable

Comment: @ChristopherW: Are you referring to $(A)$? Then , what element in $\mathbb Z$ corresponds to, say $1/2$?

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of the existence of an injection from $A$ to $B$ as saying "$A$ has at least as many elements as $B$" and the existence of a surjection from $A$ to $B$ as saying "$B$ has at least as many elements as $A$". This is easy to see when $A$ and $B$ have a finite number of elements; the idea can be heuristically extended to infinities.

1. The injection shows that $B$ can potentially have 'more' elements than $A$. Indeed, the identity map from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ suffices for a counterexample.
2. The surjection shows $B$ has 'less' elements than $A$, implying $B$ is also countable. Rigorously, enumerate $A$ by $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$. If $B$ is finite, then we are done. If not, for any $b \in B$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a_n) = b$. Then $B$ is in a one-to-one correspondence with the subset of $\mathbb N$ generated by the $b$'s. Every infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ is countable, so $B$ is countable.